# sda1 ro, sda2 rw but with bindings to sda1! How to?

Tags: mount, fstab, bind

I try to do the following

In our fstab:

```
/dev/sda1                       /               ext2    defaults,noatime,ro       0       0
/dev/sda2                       /mnt/dd2        ext3    defaults,noatime,rw       0       1

/etc                   /mnt/dd2/binds/etc none bind 0 0
/etc                   /mnt/dd2/binds/etc none bind,remount,rw 0 0
```

The intention is, keeping **sda1** Read-Only; during the setup process we make a copy of the **/etc (sda1)** directory and store in in **/mnt/dd2/binds/etc (sda2)**

Now we still should be able to do some changes in **/etc (sda1)** but I want theses changes only be seen in **/mnt/dd2/binds/etc (sda2)**

I hope I get some help here, 'cause I'm really new with all that and my boss wants a solution!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The example says sda1 and sda2 and you say sdb1 and sdb2, is this a typo or are these 2 different disks you are referring to?

Comment: Sorry, I just fixed the typo